# Immutable Java Class with List as field

Tags: java

Can we make the class immutable which has collection as one of the fields?

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {

    private int rollNumber;
    private String name;
    private Set<String> subjects;
    private List<Integer> marks ;

    public Student(int rollNumber, String name, Set<String> subjects,
            List<Integer> marks) {
        this.rollNumber = rollNumber;
        this.name = name;
        this.subjects = Collections.unmodifiableSet(subjects);
        this.marks = Collections.unmodifiableList(marks);
        setPercentage();
    }

    private float percentage;

    public int getRollNumber() {
        return rollNumber;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Set<String> getSubjects() {
        return new HashSet<>(subjects);
    }

    public List<Integer> getMarks() {
        return new ArrayList<>(marks);
    }

    public float getPercentage() {
        return percentage;
    }

    private void setPercentage() {
        float sum = 0;

        for (Integer i : marks)
            sum = sum + i;
        if (!marks.isEmpty())
            percentage = sum / marks.size();

    }
}
```

I am not able to achieve it.

I tried:

```
Set<String> subjects= new HashSet<>();
subjects.add("Maths");
subjects.add("Science");
subjects.add("English");
List<Integer> marks1= new LinkedList<Integer>();
marks1.add(45);
marks1.add(36);
marks1.add(98);
Student student1= new Student(1, "Payal", subjects, marks1);
//student1.getSubjects().add("History");
subjects.add("History");
System.out.println(student1);
```

But subjects.add is changing the state of the object.

Please help.

Comment: remove the setter and clone the collection

Comment: @Scary Ah yes, it is in Monsieur JB's nature to write very high quality answers very quickly.  I gave him your upvote.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Glad it went to a good home

Answer (score 4):

You're making a copy of both collections before returning them from your getters. This is unnecessary, since the collections are unmodifiable (unless you want the caller to get mutable collections and not unmodifiable ones).

What is necessary is to make copies of the collections that are passed from the outside in the contructor. Otherwise, the caller can still modify the collections after they've been stored in your object:

```
this.subjects = Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<>(subjects));
this.marks = Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(marks));
```

To be truly immutable, the class and its fields should also be final.

Comment: Even if I make it unmodifiable inside,2 operations don't work..
  student1.getSubjects().add("History");
  subjects.add("History");
  System.out.println(student1);

Comment: Define "don't work". What is your new code, what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: It means The History subject gets added to student object. Which should not be allowed for the class is meant to be immutable. So once created , should not be able to change the state of the object.

Comment: That can't possibly happen if you use the code I posted in my answer. Did you?

Comment: Yes, it didn't bcoz u are also returning new list from getter and in a constructor. So Collections.unmodifiableList isn't needed.

Comment: As I said in the answer: either you return an unmodifiable list from your getters, and in that case, the copy is unnecessary, or you want to return a modifiable list, and a copy is necessary. That doesn't have anything to do with what you claimed, though: i.e. that the student class is still mutable once you fix your constructor as I said in my answer. It's not, as I have just shown. So, what is your question/problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {

private int rollNumber;
private String name;
private Set<String> subjects;
private List<Integer> marks ;

public Student(int rollNumber, String name, Set<String> subjects,
        List<Integer> marks) {
    this.rollNumber = rollNumber;
    this.name = name;
    this.subjects = new HashSet<>(subjects);
    this.marks = new ArrayList<>(marks);
    setPercentage();
}

private float percentage;

public int getRollNumber() {
    return rollNumber;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public Set<String> getSubjects() {
    return new HashSet<>(subjects);
}

public List<Integer> getMarks() {
    return new ArrayList<>(marks);
}

public float getPercentage() {
    return percentage;
}

private void setPercentage() {
    float sum = 0;

    for (Integer i : marks)
        sum = sum + i;
    if (!marks.isEmpty())
        percentage = sum / marks.size();

}
```

}

I did this. It worked. If I try these 2 operations now, no problem.

```
    Set<String> subjects= new HashSet<>();
    subjects.add("Maths");
    subjects.add("Science");
    subjects.add("English");
    List<Integer> marks1= new LinkedList<Integer>();
    marks1.add(45);
    marks1.add(36);
    marks1.add(98);
    Student student1= new Student(1, "Payal", subjects, marks1);
    student1.getSubjects().add("History");
    subjects.add("History");
    System.out.println(student1);
```

Comment: It works fine but it will create new object each time you call `student1.getSubjects()` which should not be happen.

Comment: It should return a new object else changes would happen to the same object :)

Comment: if you make it `final` a shown in my answer then it will throw an `Exception`  but not add element.

Comment: you can do that if you want it is not necessary.

Comment: No, if we make it final, still we'll be able to add elements to it. Just cannot make it point to new object.

Comment: Just try my code once it is not possible to add an element in final object and accept that answer if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {

    private final int rollNumber;
    private final String name;
    private final Set<String> subjects;
    private final List<Integer> marks;

    public Student(int rollNumber, String name, Set<String> subjects, List<Integer> marks) {
        this.rollNumber = rollNumber;
        this.name = name;
        this.subjects = new HashSet<>(subjects);
        this.marks = new ArrayList<>(marks);
        setPercentage();
    }

    private float percentage;

    public int getRollNumber() {
        return rollNumber;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Set<String> getSubjects() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(subjects);
    }

    public List<Integer> getMarks() {
        return new ArrayList<>(marks);
    }

    public float getPercentage() {
        return percentage;
    }

    private void setPercentage() {
        float sum = 0;
        for (Integer i : marks) {
            sum = sum + i;
        }
        if (!marks.isEmpty()) {
            percentage = sum / marks.size();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return subjects.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student o) {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Main Method :

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<String> sub = new HashSet<>();
        sub.add("Maths");
        sub.add("Science");
        sub.add("English");
        List<Integer> marks1 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        marks1.add(45);
        marks1.add(36);
        marks1.add(98);
        Student student1 = new Student(1, "Payal", sub, marks1);
        sub.add("History");
        System.out.println(student1);
    }
}
```

1 : Reason why other code is not working is they make collection `unmodifiableSet` and `unmodifiableList` but to the local object while we just need to create new object instead of pointing old reference.
2 : And Second prevent modification of return value, for that just make instance variable to `final` or you can create new collection object and return it, but if you do that then it create new object each time you call getXXXX method while actually you don't need that object.